# flutter animation not equally fast on different devices

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, ticker

I have simple page that contains a single `AnimationController`.
This animation is triggered on button tap.

The issue is that on some iOS devices this animation is extremely fast like 100ms instead of 1s! On Android this works fine, also in iOS and Android emulator.

```
var c = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
c.addStatusListener((AnimationStatus s) {
  if(s == AnimationStatus.completed)
    c.reverse();
  else if(s == AnimationStatus.dismissed)
    c.forward();
});

AnimationBuilder(
  animation: c,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: ColorTween(begin: Colors.blue, end: Colors.red),
      child: Text('Animate Me'),
      onPressed: () {
        c.forward();
      }
    );
  }
)
```

## Edit 1

IOS is animating at about 1s interval if duration is set to 6s.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some developper options that change the speed or something? If not, make a bug report on flutter github

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing special is turned on. Will do that, if nothing else pops out.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Flutter v. 0.9.4.

Comment: Issue is still there, I'm using Flutter 2.10.4 • channel stable, Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2.